# Azure Functions Middleware not forwarding the request to the actual function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to do auth on my functions (http triggered).

At the moment, I just want the request to actually arrive at the function, but it doesn't.

I get the following error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.Methods. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc: Failed to proxy request with ForwarderError: RequestTimedOut.

Here is my `Program.cs`:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder =>
    {
         builder.UseMiddleware<Auth>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

My auth class is as follows:

```
internal class Auth : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        await next(context);
    }
}
```

It gets to the `await next(context)` line, but it never makes it to the actual function, which is the following code:

```
[Function("MyFunc")]
public IActionResult MyFunc([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "myfunc")] HttpRequest req, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    return new OkResult();
}
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should fix it:

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication(builder =>
    {
        builder.UseMiddleware<Auth>(); // Note your middleware moves to here.
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build(); // And note, no use of .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefault()

host.Run();
```

The reason is because of (understandably!) having mixed up two different types of Isolated Function.

- `.ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication` is for the new ASP.NET Core type, and middleware is set up in here too.
- `.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults` is for the earlier type.

You were using both in combination, and I guess were getting a half and half setup of each.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#aspnet-core-integration

Comment: I was having an issue where calling my functions locally was causing them to hang and never enter the function.  This is Functions v4 in .Net 8.0.  Removing `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults` fixed my issue, and I am now able to actually execute the functions.  Thanks!